# Function "read()" forces the program to exit when typing information into dynamically allocated array

Tags: arrays, c, memory

Okay so I have a simple code here that is troubling me:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    typedef struct file{
    char name[20], extension[6];
    int s; // size in bytes
    }FILE;

    FILE read_file()
    {
      FILE u;

      printf("\nEnter file name: ");
      scanf("\n%s", u.name);

      printf("Extension: ");
      scanf("\n%s", u.extension);

      printf("Size in bytes: ");
      scanf("\n%d", u.s);

      return u;
    }

    void sort(FILE* arr, int n)
    {
      for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
      {
        for(int j=0; j<n-1; j++)
        {
            if(arr[i].s < arr[j].s)
            {
                FILE pom = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = pom;
            }        
        }
      }
    }

    int main(void)
    {
      int n;

      printf("Enter a num. of files: ");
      scanf("%d", &n);

      FILE* pn = (FILE*)malloc(n * sizeof(FILE));
      for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
      {
        printf("%d. file:", i+1);
        read_file(pn+i);
      }

      sort(pn, n);

      printf("\nNum.     File name      Extension      Size");
      printf("\n===   ==============   ===========   ========");
      for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
      {
        printf("\n%-4d %-22s %-12s %d", i+1, pn->name, pn->extension, pn->s);
      }
    }
```

Code runs fine when you type in the information for the first file in the dynamically allocated array, but as soon as you need to enter information for the second file, the code exits.

This part over here:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d. file:", i+1);
        read_file(pn+i);
    }
```

I believe that I have to declare a variable of FILE data type which function "read()" will return, but the compiler still shows error even though I (let's presume) declare:

```
FILE p = read_file(pn+i);
```

**Edit!**

> Renamed "read()" function to "read_file()".

I would gladly appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You seem to be thinking that this is a thread in a forum. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: If the problem you want to discuss occurs before `sort()` in main, then please focus your question and your [mre] on that. I.e. delte everything afterwards and everything used only afterwards and all the description which is irrelevant for the problem you want to discuss.

Comment: Please explain why read() has a return value but you ignore what is returned.

Comment: @Yunnosch Hi there. Okay, I will try to edit most of the code and focus on a certain part of it. I'm not exaclty sure what is causing the issue here, but as I said I will try to be as specific as possible. Thank you.

Comment: Make a [mre], if you cannot get it any smaller but it still can be built to demonstrate what you observe then it is a good enough one.

Comment: `read` is also the name of a standard POSIX function.  That's not *inherently* a problem, but it does set you up for problems and therefore is poor style.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I also worried about that, but it obviously the assignment author is to be blamed for that....

Comment: On the other hand, the combination of `#include <stdio.h>` and declaring `typedef ... FILE` is broken.  Your compiler should be complaining, and undefined behavior results, on account of the identifier `FILE` already being defined as a type alias.  Don't choose names that collide with the standard library.

Comment: Does the problem still occur if you delete `sort()` and everything after it? If not, then I would not suspect the for-loop....

Comment: You are passing an argument to (now) `read_file()`, but that function does not accept any arguments.  Undefined behavior results, though in practice, this probably is not the reason for the crash.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately my hands are tied in this exercise to some extent. Function names are written in different language, so I translated everything properly. Here, I need to stick to function prototypes as I cannot edit them(the university assistant doesn't allow that). If there is something that I need to specifically edit or explain again, I will gladly do it.

Comment: What happens if you only delete the call to `sort()`?

Comment: `scanf("\n%d", u.s)` is wrong.  It should be `scanf("\n%d", &u.s)`.  (The other two `scanf` calls are fine as-is.)  This one has a decent chance of being the actual source of the problem.

Comment: I think you are calling the `read_file()` function incorrectly.
It should be: `pn[i] = read_file();`

Comment: @ign0r, whatever limitations there may be on what you can or cannot do are orthogonal to the validity of the code presented with respect to the C language.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Oh right, I missed the address operator next to the `u.s` when reading the integer value. Thank you. I will let you know as soon as I test the code.

Comment: @Shafa95 Okay, that has been dealt with. Thank you for the heads up.

Comment: @JohmBollinger @Shafa95 That fixed the issue. Code runs flawlessly now. Thank you very much. I presumed that it had to be something wrong with calling the `read_file()` function. Now that the `&` operator has been added and edited `pn[i] = read_file()`, everything is okay.

Answer (score 1):

**The code presented has at least these major problems:**

1. If you `#include <stdio.h>` then you may not define `FILE` as an ordinary identifier, including a typedef name.  Doing so violates a language constraint, so a conforming compiler is obligated to emit a diagnostic about that.  If it accepts the code then the resulting behavior is undefined.
2. Given that `u.s` has type `int`, the call

   ```
       scanf("\n%d", u.s);
   ```

   is wrong and produces undefined behavior.  The intended function call appears to have been

   ```
       scanf("\n%d", &u.s);
   ```

   There is a better than average probability that the UB attending this mistake would manifest as a program crash.  Some C compilers would have diagnosed this error for you, so if yours did not (you *are* compiling this locally for testing purposes, right?) then you should consider getting a better compiler.
3. The function call `read_file(pn+i);` is incorrect because function `read_file()` does not accept any arguments.  Even a pretty poor C compiler ought to have issued a diagnostic about that, so either you are not paying attention to the compiler's diagnostic messages or you are in desperate need of a better compiler.  Typically, however, the UB associated with an error of this kind does not manifest as a program crash, and might not have a perceivable manifestation at all.

**There is also this lesser issue:**

4. The program ignores the return value of `read_file()`.  This is allowed, but it is not what you appear to want do.  The result is that the data that are read are not written to the object to which your `pn` pointer points.  The program output should give evidence of this.

Answer (score -1):

The code

```
FILE* pn = (FILE*)malloc(n * sizeof(FILE));
```

is actually allocate a memory space for a pointer of "FILE". In this memory space resides only one pointer. If you dereferencing that pointer, you can only access one "FILE".

If you want to allocate memory for an array of "FILE"s. I suggest that you allocate a memory space for an array of pointer of "FILE". For example

```
FILEx** pn_arr = (FILEx**)malloc(n * sizeof(FILEx*));
```

In this space, you keep n pointers of "FILE" that you can track each file by the pointer of pointer "pn_arr".

Then, each time you try to assign data to a "FILE". You should allocate a new space to it. For example:

```
FILEx* pn = (FILEx*)malloc(sizeof(FILEx));
```

I try to fix your problem. Mine implementation is as following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct file{
    char name[20], extension[6];
    int s; // size in bytes
}FILEx;

void read_file(FILEx* pn)
{
    printf("\nEnter file name: ");
    scanf("\n%s", pn->name);

    printf("Extension: ");
    scanf("\n%s", pn->extension);

    printf("Size in bytes: ");
    scanf("\n%d", &pn->s);
}



 int main(void)
{
   int n;

   printf("Enter a num. of files: ");
   scanf("%d", &n);

   FILEx** pn_arr = (FILEx**)malloc(n * sizeof(FILEx*));

  for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
     printf("%d. file:", i+1);
     FILEx* pn = (FILEx*)malloc(sizeof(FILEx));
     read_file(pn);
     pn_arr[i] = pn;
   }

 //sort(pn, n);

 printf("\nNum.     File name      Extension      Size");
 printf("\n===   ==============   ===========   ========");
 for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
 {
    printf("\n%-4d %-22s %-12s %d", i+1, pn_arr[i]->name
    , pn_arr[i]->extension, pn_arr[i]->s);
 }
}
```

Note that I didn't test your sort() function. If you are going to use pointer of pointer to implement the array of "FILE". You should modify your sort() function to make it work. I think that will be easy to implement a sort() function if you use pointer of pointer to keep track of "FILE". Because you just need to exchange pointer to rearrange the order of "FILE".

Comment: Contrary to your claim, `malloc(n * sizeof(FILE));` reserves space sufficient for `n` objects of type `FILE` (*not* merely a single object of type `FILE *`).  Casting the result to type `FILE *` does not change that, and is in fact redundant in this context.  It is furthermore unclear why you suggest allocating space for several pointers when the OP in fact wants space for the `FILE` objects themselves.  It is absolutely unnecessary for the OP's purposes to dynamically allocate space for a bunch of pointers in addition to allocating space for separate objects for each of them to point to.

Comment: I think that using pointers will be much easier to sort the objects. You are right, malloc(n * sizeof(FILE)); reserves space sufficient for n objects of type FILE. But after we read these n "FILE", how do you sort these n objects?

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with the OP's existing sort, which sorts the structure array itself, not an auxiliary array of pointers.  And this is pretty much all tangential to the question, which concerns why the program is crashing.